# Does wash sale apply if I buy stock on 2 two different dates and sell it later

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, wash-sale

Consider the following scenario.

```
I buy 100 company ABC stocks at $100 each whose worth is $10000 on jan 1

I buy 50 company ABC stocks at $70 each whose worth is $3500 on jan 10

I sold 150 company ABC stocks at $95 whose worth is $14250 on feb 3
```

Is wash rule applicable for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is wash rule applicable for this?

No - because you made a *gain* on the sale.  You paid $13,500 for the stock and sold it for $14,250.

The wash rule prevents you from claiming a *loss* if you buy the same stock again within 30 days.  You have no loss to claim, so the rule does not apply.

Comment: what about this. bought a stock and sold for gain and bought a stock and sold for loss on the same day. Net loss is $4. can i claim this loss for taxes?.

Comment: So long as you don't buy the stock _again_ within 30 days then yes you can claim the net loss.

Answer (score 1):

Wash sale applies. If you purchase shares within 30 days of that Feb 3 sell date, the wash sale kicks in, preventing the loss on that sale, and deferring it into the new shares.